# Wordpress Custom URL 404

Tags: php, wordpress

Newbie to wordpress.

I have been thrust into updating a plugin that someone else wrote.  The task was to update the permalink for custom post.  I was able to set the permalink to what they wanted http://xxxx.com/jobs/2015-1114/. However when you go to the link you get page not found.  Any help would be appreciated.  All I have to work with is the plugin code.  I cannot use another plugin to help.

Comment: Check your database to make sure your page has the correct permalink. Easiest way is to export the db and to do a string search for your new perma link.

Comment: Thanks.  The permalink is not in the database but when you edit the page the permalink under the post title is correct. The client wanted the permalink to be the job number.